# Sequentially numbering instances based on value in another column "resetting"

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe that tracks sales of a jackpot-style game.  The jackpot rises until someone hits it, then resets to either 100000 or 125000.  I'd like to number the jackpot runs throughout the data.  The data looks like this:

```
sales     jp   newrun
367890  125000  1
359497  225000  0
686205  420000  0
693497  560000  0
405268  125000  1
316572  125000  1
438263  225000  0
586050  375000  0
902894  600000  0
377326  125000  1
369216  225000  0
400330  125000  1
433491  225000  0
681295  410000  0
881837  600000  0
```

Where newrun is a dummy that indicates that the jackpot reset.  Here is the dput():

```
structure(list(sales = c(367890, 359497, 686205, 693497, 405268, 
316572, 438263, 586050, 902894, 377326, 369216, 400330, 433491, 
681295, 881837), 
    jp = c(125000, 225000, 420000, 560000, 125000, 
    125000, 225000, 375000, 6e+05, 125000, 225000, 125000, 225000, 
    410000, 6e+05),
    newrun = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sales", "jp", "newrun"), row.names = c(NA, 
    15L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am looking to end up with:

```
sales     jp   newrun  run
367890  125000  1       1
359497  225000  0       1
686205  420000  0       1
693497  560000  0       1
405268  125000  1       2
316572  125000  1       3
438263  225000  0       3
586050  375000  0       3
902894  600000  0       3
377326  125000  1       4
369216  225000  0       4
400330  125000  1       5
433491  225000  0       5
681295  410000  0       5
881837  600000  0       5
```

I tried:

```
>runs<-c(1, cumsum(diff(as.logical(rowSums(
     c5a[c("newrun")] != 0)))>0) + 1)
```

which almost worked, but it didn't recognize instances where the jackpot was hit on the first day (when it was at either $100,000 or $125,000).  It just lumped those in with the next run (so, in the above example, instead of runs going 1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3, it went 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did i miss something or you just want :

```
c5a$run <- cumsum(c5a$newrun)
c5a
    sales     jp newrun run
1  367890 125000      1   1
2  359497 225000      0   1
3  686205 420000      0   1
4  693497 560000      0   1
5  405268 125000      1   2
6  316572 125000      1   3
7  438263 225000      0   3
8  586050 375000      0   3
9  902894 600000      0   3
10 377326 125000      1   4
11 369216 225000      0   4
12 400330 125000      1   5
13 433491 225000      0   5
14 681295 410000      0   5
15 881837 600000      0   5
```

Comment: Nope.  I was clearly just way over-thinking what needed to be done to get that result.  Thank you.

Comment: Lol, it happens sometimes ;-)